# New surfaceview when returning from home screen to running application

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

Trying to delete/destroy my old surfaceview when I leave my app (home/back button) and create a new one in order to "restart" the app when the user goes back into the app.

I only have one Activity (Launcher activity) and so i think I got to do it in the onRestart() method:

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();

    AppSurfaceView mySV = new AppSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySV);
}
```

But the screen remains black.

On the first launch of the app (no process in the app task list), it all works properly - heres the onCreate method of my launcher activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //Force Landscape
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



    AppSurfaceView mySV = new AppSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySV);
}
```

Edit

```
AppSurfaceView mySV;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    mySV = new AppSurfaveView(this);
    setContentView(mySV);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    mySV = null;

}
```

Comment: See http://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onResume and onPause callbacks instead of onRestart and onCreate.

```
AppSurfaceView mySV;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mySV = null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mySV = new AppSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySV);
}
```

This flow explains to you android Activity lifecycle.

[image]

Comment: Have changed it. Still works for the first start of the app, but when i leave and come back to it its still just black. Ideas? Thanks